# [React][React-Leaflet] Updating position after changing radius

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geolocation, position, markers

I am working on a React-app to find a soccer club near the user position, I want to let the user change the radius around him in order to find some results in his area.

So for now the default value of the area is 10km (not very exact), as you can see when I launch the app some circles are outside the radius :

[Markers outside radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWhg9.png)

It may be an issue of LatLng, but there is also an issue when I update the range of the radius, in the image just below I increase the radius to 25km but the array of the results stills the same, my code don't update their position:

[Markers not refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/150BF.png)

I know not all data is displayed and I'm not sure of how to do this with react-leaflet

See my code juste below :

https://www.zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/11/gmq5.png

Thanks for reading guys,

Let me know if you need more code,

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you share the minimal required code here or in a sandbox e.g. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: Sorry, I had and issue with Codesandbox so i made a demo version here : https://vends-twingo2.netlify.app/

Comment: complete code hosted in a image here : https://ibb.co/rfbtvhj

Comment: You webpage turns white if I block my position :/